# Objective-C equivalent of Java enums or "static final" objects

Tags: java, objective-c, constants

I'm trying to find an Objective-C equivalent to either Java enum types, or "public static final" objects, like:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    private String str;
    private int val;
    FOO( "foo string", 42 ),
    BAR( "bar string", 1337 );
    MyEnum( String str, int val ) {
        this.str = str;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

or,

```
public static final MyObject FOO = new MyObject( "foo", 42 );
```

I need to create constants that are constants (of course), and accessible anywhere that imports the associated .h file, or globally.  I've tried the following with no success:

Foo.h:

```
static MyEnumClass* FOO;
```

Foo.m:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    FOO = [[MyEnumClass alloc] initWithStr:@"foo string" andInt:42];
}
```

When I did this and tried to use the `FOO` constant, it had no values in the `str` and `val` variables.  I have verified through the use of `NSLog` calls that `initialize` is in fact being called.

Also, even though I am referencing the `FOO` variable in the test block of code, Xcode highlighted the line in the .h file shown above with the comment `'FOO' defined but not used`.

I'm totally baffled!  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `extern` instead of `static`:

Foo.h:

```
extern MyEnumClass* FOO;
```

Foo.m:

```
MyEnumClass* FOO = nil; // This is the actual instance of FOO that will be shared by anyone who includes "Foo.h".  That's what the extern keyword accomplishes.

+ (void)initialize {
    if (!FOO) {
        FOO = [[MyEnumClass alloc] initWithStr:@"foo string" andInt:42];
    }
}
```

`static` means that the variable is private within a single compilation unit (e.g., a single .m file).  So using `static` in a header file will create private FOO instances for each .m file that includes Foo.h, which is not what you would ever want.

Comment: +1. I would add to this: you have to also arrange to have +[Foo intialize] called. It won't be called until there is some other message sent to Foo. And [FOO someMessage] won't do it, because FOO is initially nil. This is part of the reason why we tend to use things like +[Foo sharedFoo] instead of globals like this.